# .Find searches in wrong column (vba) (fixed)

Tags: excel, vba, find

Edit : This is fixed, i had a merged cell from the F to I column.

i try to find a string variable in different columns.
When it is found i want the value of the cell next to it. (sometimes left sometimes right)

the first part seems to work fine (column F)
But when i try to do this again in column I my .Find stil searches in column F?
(landloc is stil "F9" in the I column)

any suggestions?

Currently i have this code:

```
Sub onderlingdp()
Worksheets("Tournooi").Activate
Dim land As String
Dim land2 As String
Dim land3 As String
Dim landdp As Integer
Dim land2dp As Integer
Dim land3dp As Integer
Dim landloc As Range
Dim land2loc As Range
Dim land3loc As Range

land = Range("B7").Value
land2 = Range("B8").Value
land3 = Range("b9").Value

landdp = 0
land2dp = 0
land3dp = 0

Columns("F:F").Select

Set landloc = Selection.Find(what:=land, after:=ActiveCell)
If landloc Is Nothing Then GoTo Skip Else
Range(landloc.Address).Select
landdp = landdp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Skip:


Set land2loc = Selection.Find(what:=land2, after:=ActiveCell)
If land2loc Is Nothing Then GoTo skip2 Else
Range(land2loc.Address).Select
land2dp = land2dp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
skip2:

Set land3loc = Selection.Find(what:=land3, after:=ActiveCell)
If land3loc Is Nothing Then GoTo Skip3 Else
Range(land3loc.Address).Select
land3dp = land3dp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Skip3:

' NEXT Column'
Columns("I:I").Select

Set landloc = Selection.Find(what:=land, after:=ActiveCell)
If landloc Is Nothing Then GoTo iSkip Else
Range(landloc.Address).Select
landdp = landdp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
iSkip:


Set land2loc = Selection.Find(what:=land2, after:=ActiveCell)
If land2loc Is Nothing Then GoTo iskip2 Else
Range(land2loc.Address).Select
land2dp = land2dp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
iskip2:

Set land3loc = Selection.Find(what:=land3, after:=ActiveCell)
If land3loc Is Nothing Then GoTo iSkip3 Else
Range(land3loc.Address).Select
land3dp = land3dp + ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
iSkip3:
```

Comment: If I read it correctly you refer to finding in the column of the active cell. You need to offset this or define the column.